# Can you solve for $f$ in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}} = -2\log\left(\frac{1}{3.7x}+ \frac{2.51}{y\sqrt{f}}\right)$?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve for $f$ in the equation below.

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}} = -2\log\left(\frac{1}{3.7x}+ \frac{2.51}{y\sqrt{f}}\right)$$

I keep getting different answers every time I try to solve for $f$ so I'm starting to assume it's not possible.

If you choose to respond I don't need step by step. I just want to know if it's possible and if it is, what answer you got.

This was one of my attempts:

$$f = (-18.5x - \frac{9.287x}{y})^2$$

As requested.... Here is my attempted work:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean isolating $f$ on one side of the equation?

Comment: @Ajay yes, I'm using this formula from a book and it gave me the equation in this format.

Comment: Please include all of your working.

Comment: If you do some renaming of constants and such, you can boil it down to an equation of the form $c+dz=\log(1+z)$. This cannot be solved in closed form without invoking the Lambert W.